The restriction of a blow up to a subscheme is the the blow up of this subscheme at the intersection of it and the center.
Suppose $Z \subset X$ is a closed subscheme and $Y \subset X$ is another closed subscheme. Let $\mu : \mathrm{Bl}_{Z} (X) \to X$ be the blow-up of $X$ at Z. Then is $\mu|_{Y} : \mu^{-1}(Y) \to Y$ the blow-up of $Y$ at $Y\cap Z$?
I know it is true for algebraic varieties over $\mathbb C$, but I do not know if it is true for varieties over any field, even schemes. It would be very appreciated if some results about $\mathbb R$-varieties were given. I just need references, you don't have to write a proof.

Sorry to be nitpicky, but what you wrote it not strictly true, since this preimage might contain a copy of the exceptional divisor and hence not be irreducible. You want the strict transform instead.

Oh, yes, it should the the strict transform of Y.

Thanks, everyone,  I found it in Vakil, Lemma 26.2.6.
